# WinFormApp won't connect to the database

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, connection

No clue why this won't work.  It has worked before.

I do have the connection string in the app.config as well.  I get the MySqlException error saying unable to connect to any database.

I made sure the firewall wasn't stopping it and I opened the ports on my router.  All the references are in place too.  This should work.

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString;
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
            Conn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("DB Connected");
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Are you able to connect from MySQL workbench?

Comment: I’m connecting to a MySQL database on a server.  I’m not familiar with work bench.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
string connetionString = null;
        MySqlConnection cnn ;
        connetionString = "server=localhost;database=testDB;uid=root;pwd=abc123;";
        cnn = new MySqlConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show ("Connection Open ! ");
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }
```

Comment: I already tried my code in that configuration..... was a no go

Comment: you can see this link : [mysql](https://medium.com/@REPTILEHAUS/c-and-mysql-windows-forms-insert-into-db-2462ae50e9d8)

Comment: I'll try it.  But I think it isn't the code I think something is blocking the connection.

Comment: Just tried it...get the same result.  Is there something I'm missing in the app.config?

Comment: MySQL server is running ?

Comment: Yes,  a hosted server.  All other databases I have on it are working and working fine...just not in this winformapp.

Comment: Just found out that MySQL is not supported for WinFormapps for security reasons..../  Have to use MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Databases cannot be used in WinFormApp due to security risks on a remote server.  MS SQL DB's are supported.  I didn't know that and I see a lot of questions about this so if anyone can't connect this may be why.